# Question about a linear algebra detail of Kernel PCA

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces, principal-component-analysis

As is shown in this question [kernel pca eigenproblem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156993/linear-kernel-pca-get-corresponding-dimension) and many other refernce materials about kernel PCA. They all point out that the solution of $K^2a_j=\lambda_jnKa_j$ and $Ka_j=\lambda_jna_j$ only differ by eigenvectors with $0$ eigenvalue, where $K$ is the Gram matrix of $\phi(x_1),\phi(x_2),\cdots,\phi(x_n).$ However, I can't clearly see this conclusion and what it means.